# ListView doesn't change its size in Java FX

Tags: java, listview, javafx-8

i added a ListView in a VBox, which is located a the left of a BorderPane. It actually works well, but if I change the window size while the application is running, I have the problem that the ListView doesn't change its size. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?:) Code:

package main;

public class ScreenBuilder extends Application{

```
BorderPane parent;
    HBox top;
    HBox bottom;
    VBox left;
        ScrollPane pane;
        ListView<String> list;
    VBox right;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    parent = new BorderPane();
    parent.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 2px; -fx-border-color: #2e8b57");

        top = new HBox();
        parent.setTop(top);


        bottom = new HBox();
        parent.setBottom(bottom);


        left = new VBox();
        parent.setLeft(left);

            list = new ListView<String>(initList());
            pane = new ScrollPane(list);
            pane.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 2px; -fx-border-color: #2e8b57");
            left.getChildren().add(pane);


        right = new VBox();
        parent.setRight(right);


    stage.setScene(new Scene(parent));
    stage.show();

}

private ObservableList<String> initList(){
    ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list.add("Hallo1");
    list.add("Hallo2");
    list.add("Hallo3");
    list.add("Hallo4");
    list.add("Hallo5");
    list.add("Hallo6");
    list.add("Hallo7");
    list.add("Hallo8");
    list.add("Hallo9");
    return list;
}





public static void main(String[] args){
    launch();
}
```

}

Comment: Need code! Post code!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **ListView doesn't change its size**? Do you mean that the `VBox` itself stays unscaled? Or just the `ListView` inside it? Also, please provide [minimal code to reproduce this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: okay the box works correctly! code is down there.when i put a border around the scroll pane there are two borders when i change the window size: one that says around the list and one that works correctly and is around the whole window...

Comment: The `BorderPane` resizes the `ListView` to its preferred size. What is the expected working? Do you want the `ListView` to vertically fill its parent? Or would you like horizontal growing?

Comment: Do you really need that `ScrollPane`? `ListView` already gives scrollbars if cells exceeded size.